# Random int still generating numbers that are either below or above the scope?

Tags: c++

How my program should work is that, in the first instance, the program would generate a number for `int secretNumber` ( which will never change) and then start generating random numbers for `int guess`. The goal of the program to continue generating numbers for `int guess` until `int guess` has the same value as `int secretNumber`. However, I was trying to fashion it so that, if `int guess` generated a number that was either lesser or more than the number of `int secretNumber`, the scope would get smaller.

In other words, if `int secretNumber` equals `45` and `int guess` was given the randomly generated number of `10`, then anything before `10` will never be selected, and `10` will become the new `Low`. And if `secretNumber` was `45` and `int guess` was given the number `50`, then anything after `50` will never be picked. And, so, in turn, the scope will get smaller and smaller until it either becomes so that there are only a few possible choices left to pick, or until it becomes so that the number assigned to `secretNumber` is the only possible number left.

I tried to establish this by changing the `High` and `Low` with each guess the computer will make. In other words, if the number was too high, then the new cap would be the previously made guess but subtracted by `1`, and, if the number was too low, then the `guess` would be the `guess` but added with `1`. The code would eventually find a match between `int guess` and `int secretNumber`, but, for some reason, every loop will hold the possibility of generating a number that would be higher than the set cap or the set lowest possible number.

So let's say the computer was to generate `30` for the first round, but that number could have been lower than the number needed to win the game. The new lowest possible number would be `31`, and, with that, any number that is under `31` would be impossible to pick. However, in the next round, it would end up picking `27`.

Such is a problem that I have been running into over the past few hours, and I am just lost in what I am actually doing wrong. I thought my method should easily give me the result that I want, but this is happening and I just don't understand the reasoning behind it. If anyone here can explain my error, I would truly appreciate it.

```cpp
int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int secretNumber = rand() % 64 + 1;
    int tries = 0;
    int High = 64;
    int Low = 1;
    int guess = rand() % High + Low;
    cout << "\tWelcome to Guess My Number\n\n";

    do {
        int guess = rand() % High + Low;
        ++tries;
        if (guess > secretNumber) {
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";
            cout << "\n"<<guess;
            int High = guess - 1;
        }
        else if (guess < secretNumber) {
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
            cout <<"\n"<< guess;
            int Low = guess + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nThat's it!You got it in" << tries << "guesses!\n";
            system("pause");
            return 0;

        }
    } while (guess != secretNumber);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Way too much text!  Simply provide an example input, the actual output, and the desired output.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, There's still some valuable explanation in there about reducing the possible guess range, but I agree it is overly wordy.

Comment: This isn't everything, but compiler warnings help if you turn them on and test with multiple compilers: *warning: unused variable 'High' [-Wunused-variable]*. Similarly for `Low`. Stepping through with a debugger and examining the state of the program also helps to isolate where an issue really happens.

Comment: side note: don't use modulus to get rand() into a range; instead use division. If rand() is a LCG then lower bits are not as random. Although in your program I doubt that's a concern...

Comment: Can you sum up the problem in a few sentences at the bottom?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a random number between `High` and `Low`?

Comment: That is basically what this program is trying to accomplish. It is just that, for some reason, it is breaking through the range set for it ( when I do int low = guess + 1 or int High = guess - 1), thus making it so that it generates numbers that should actually not have been generated at all.

Comment: @pkpulsefall If you take a look at my answer, it will give you a detailed explination of the reason why it's not quite working how you intended; as well as the very simple fix you need to make.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First take a look at @EJP's answer and remove the `int` from in front of `High` and `Low` in the while loop. You are redeclaring them and that's your first problem...

> If `int secretNumber` equals 45 and `int guess` was given the randomly generated number of 10, then anything before 10 will never be selected.

Nope. Not the way you're currently calculating `int guess` it won't.  Let's take a closer look.

#### What you have

```
int guess = rand() % High + Low;
```

For your first iteration through the loop this will work great.  Your high value is still 64 and your low value is still 1.  Your first guess will be within that range. Now what happens in the second time through the loop when using your example `Low` becomes 11?  Now you have `guess = rand() % 64 + 11;`. So the new possible values of guess could be anywhere between 11 and 75. Whoops that extends past the possible range of what `secretNumber` (1-64) could be!

#### What you need

You want your `guess` to be within the possible range of `High` and `Low` values through each iteration. Basically you need to shrink the set of possible answers after each guess.  This can be accomplished by replacing your current expression for `guess` with the following line of code.

```
int guess = rand() % (High - Low) + Low;
```

Now `guess` will give you a random number between your most recent calculated High and Low values.

#### How it works

Continuing with your example, your next guess will now be constrained to the possible range like so: `guess = rand() % (64 - 11) + 11;` Using this, your initial computation of `rand() % (64 - 11)` will have to be a value between 0 and 53. This isn't what you want but when you add your new lower limit of 11 back in, your `guess` now will be within the newly determined possible valid range of 11 to 64. I hope this answer and explanation helps you.

Comment: `Low` never becomes 11 in the OP's code. *Another variable* called `Low` becomes 11.

Comment: Why the downvote? Yeah redeclaring `High` and `Low` within the loop is a problem but it wasn't the problem OP asked about.

Comment: Hi. Very sorry for not responding sooner. I followed what you said and, in the end, it worked like a charm! The only thing I did differently was the place the (High - Low) in a different int and then used that int within the equation. But it is basically the same thing that you were talking about, and it gives me what I want. Truly appreciate the help. I was going to talk to my teacher about an error I got, however, but I guess I'll ask you guys here.

Comment: See, there will be a chance where the equation will attempt to divide by 0 ( that is what I took from it), and so the system will crash. I will run more tests to see if I can rediscover the error, but, if you have an idea on what is happening, do you mind telling me how to get around it? Again, appreciate the help.

Comment: Ran the code again and got this error: Unhandled exception at 0x00AD244C in ConsoleApplication6.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero. occurred

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring `High` and `Low` instead of assigning to the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say guess is 20, if `guess < secretnumber`, you increase `low` to 20, but don’t change `high`.
So the next random number will be `rand() % 64 + 20` which could be up to 63 + 20.

One way to resolve it is to reduce high while you increase low.

Answer (score 0):

As EJP mentions, you're redeclaring High and Low. Also, you should use lower case letters for variables. In general you should use the type of a variable only once during the execution, usually at the beginning of the program, where they're first declared.
I made those changes, tested them and now it works as intended:

```
int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int secretNumber = rand() % 64 + 1;
    int tries = 0;
    int high = 64;
    int low = 1;
    int guess;// = rand() % High + Low;
    cout << "\tWelcome to Guess My Number\n\n";

    do {
        guess = rand() % high + low;
        ++tries;
        if (guess > secretNumber) {
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";
            cout << "\n"<<guess;
            high = guess - 1;
        }
        else if (guess < secretNumber) {
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
            cout <<"\n"<< guess;
            low = guess + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nThat's it!You got it in" << tries << "guesses!\n";
            system("pause");
            return 0;

        }
    } while (guess != secretNumber);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also take into account what Aganju says, it will take extra iterations and some results could be out of range. I just fixed the technical part of your solution, but it would still not be an optimal one unless you change what he suggests.